# Slow API response time with Django Apache and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, apache, optimization, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I am having a POST API in django and I've installed the New Relic APM for the application. The time taken by django to process the request is around 250ms but the response time (measured from postman) is around 2.5 seconds.

My architecture is set up on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

1. A load balancer (with SSL) is used as the web interface
2. A linux instance is running Apache along with the Django app via WSGI

The response time of consecutive requests vary from 2.5 secs to 600 ms. How can I identify the issue and bring down the response time to less than 500ms

Here's my wsgi.conf for http.d

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/test_proj/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIPassAuthorization On


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>

LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

[image: New Relic Stats]

[image: Postman Response times]

Comment: does it take that much even without processing? Are you sending back much data?

Comment: Would be useful to see how you have configured mod_wsgi in Apache for a start.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton AWS automatically configures WSGI for Apache. I've added the config file here.

Comment: Have you tried using any APM product such as New Relic or Datadog to work out what your application code is actually doing?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've attached New Relics data where the avg response time for app is 250ms - 300 ms but the end to end time is around 1.5 - 2 secs for the first request and then it comes down to 500ms-700ms

Comment: The high first response time is because it has load your application code. To avoid that should use preloading. Instead of using ``WSGIProcessGroup``, add ``process-group=wsgi`` and ``application-group=%{GLOBAL}`` options to end of ``WSGIScriptAlias`` config line. See what you get then.

Comment: Did you solve this?